# How to Override a default method?

Tags: android, overriding, navigation-drawer

We have this line of code of in **Class A**

```
 drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
```

When press `ctrl` + `left click`, we get this code,which cannot be changed.

```
public void addDrawerListener(@NonNull DrawerListener listener) {
        if (listener == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (mListeners == null) {
            mListeners = new ArrayList<DrawerListener>();
        }
        mListeners.add(listener);
    }
```

We would like it display `null` if listener is `null`, so we `Override` this method and add into **Class A**.

```
    @Override
    public void addDrawerListener(@NonNull DrawerLayout.DrawerListener listener) {
        if (listener == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        if (mListeners == null) {
            mListeners = new ArrayList<DrawerLayout.DrawerListener>();
        }
        mListeners.add(listener);
    }
```

But then we get

```
Method does not override method from its superclass
```

What should we do if we would like to change `addDrawerListener` ?

**Edit**

My class is extends to AppCompatActivity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            RssFragment fragment = new RssFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);

    }
```

The navigation drawer not functioning after I added the part of code

```
 if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            RssFragment fragment = new RssFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
```

But if I remove, the navigation drawer works fine. We would like to debug from there.

Comment: above code is fine...what is R.id.fragment_container..i mean inside your drawerLayout in xml?

Comment: @AshwiniViolet It contains `toolbar` and `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout`

Comment: you know what...you declared toolbar in your activity but in reality it's in your fragment class. even i'm confused why this even working.why that toolbar is not null.

Comment: there is two way for you now..first move toolbar into activity and second you can set drawer inside fragment class by calling getActivity.findViewById() for drawer...this way drawer still  will be in your activity but this also useless if you changed your fragment ...

Comment: One more way... You can do reverse... You can access toolbar in activity by finding fragment after setting it... But then you can't change your fragment... Else you will loos toolbar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> we get this code,which cannot be changed.

That is from a library. You cannot modify the compiled edition of a library.

> What should we do if we would like to change addDrawerListener ?

Extend whatever Java class `drawer` is (`DrawerLayout`, probably) and override `addDrawerListener()` there, adding your logic and chaining to the superclass implementation for the existing logic. Then, use your subclass instead of the base class wherever you are defining `drawer`.

Comment: @JohnJoe: Your edit does not appear to have anything to do with your original question.

Answer (score 2):

It is because your **class A** is not a subclass of the class `DrawerLayout` which contains the method `addDrawerListener`.

If you really want to override the method, you will need to create a new class that extends the class `DrawerLayout` and use that new class to instantiate your drawer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this if you want to perform some task when drawer open,close.

```
 drawer.addDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(@NonNull View drawerView, float slideOffset) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(@NonNull View drawerView) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(@NonNull View drawerView) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {

        }
    });
```

here `DrawerListener` is an interface that declared in `DrawerLayout` 
as we already know we have to implement all methods of a interface if we implementing in our class

in your case you not doing that so `Method does not override method from its superclass`

in your DrawerLayout class you will see this interface when you scroll up

Another option is extending the class as **Nabin Bhandari** suggested

Comment: so where should I put the `addDrawerListener` method if I want to use the method you suggest?

Comment: can you tell us what you want to do by overriding this method. then i can tell according your need, which method you use